# How to get the clicked element in React Hooks using useRef

Tags: reactjs

I was playing with React Hooks and I tried to create an accordion.
I am trying to itreate it from an array.
So I have 2data, When I consoled the index, I'm getting the exact index of the clicked button. But when I consoled the ref , I'm getting the ref of the second one but not the first one.

How is this happening? Is it a bug in react?

Here is the sample code

```
 const content = useRef(null);


    const accordionClick = (id) => {
        setHeightState(setActive === false ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`);
        SetCustomIndex(id);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(content );
    };

 items.general.map((data, index) => (
      <div className={`accordion-container`} key={index}>
         <button className{`accordion ${setActive}`} onClick{()=>accordionClick(index)}>
            {data}
          </button>

           <div
              className={`panel`}
              ref={content}
              data-id={index}
              style={{
                height: `${setHeight}`,
             }}
               data-id={index}
            >
             <p className="description-14">{data.item.main}</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: That's because you use the same ref for several DOM nodes rendered by the cycle. Why do you need to show/hide elements by setting the panels' height? Is there a strict requirement? What if I can offer another way to do so?

Comment: So that I can get the slide in and out animation , If you have a better approach then please I would love to check that out

Comment: I got it fixed. I should have figured out about giving index to the ref aswell. Thanks for your time too man <3

Comment: Uhh. Height animation to "auto"...
I would create some wrapper for the panel that would handle the visibility and height animation and just pass the visibility flag to it based on the currently selected `id` in the state.
The way you're trying do solve your task now is not the declarative React way.

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko ohh, I got your pont , I'll try that then. Thank you :)

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko I tried but failed , Do you have any link to the method you were talking about ?

Comment: The answer will be too big for the comment. I believe that this is a good topic for a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `map()`, use ref with Array

```
const inputRef = useRef([]);

ref={el => inputRef.current[index] = el}
```

Usage

```
inputRef.current[index];
```

---

Minimum reproducible sample:

```js
const App = () => {
const list = [...Array(4).keys()];
const inputRef = React.useRef([]);
const handler = idx => e => {
  const next = inputRef.current[idx + 1];
  if (next) {
    next.focus()
  }
};
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="input_boxes">
      {list.map(x => (
        <input
          key={x}
          ref={el => inputRef.current[x] = el}
          onChange={handler(x)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ohhhhh,Man thank you. I should have guessed this . Been working for 12hours straight , My brain must be exhausted, THANK YOU SO MUCH THOUGH